# Absolute Value Integral

Tags: definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_{0.1}^{1}|(\pi)( x^{-2})sin(\pi \cdot x^{-1})|dx$$

The above has to be computed without a calculator.

I know that $$\frac{d}{dx}[cos(\pi \cdot x^{-1})] = (\pi)( x^{-2})sin(\pi \cdot x^{-1})$$

Applying the limits to the left hand side of the above equation, the initial integral evaluates to  $-2$. However, the $18$. How do I get 18?

Comment: Are you integrating $ f = \lvert \pi x^{-2} \sin(\pi x^{-1}) \rvert$ or $f = \pi x^{-2} \sin(\pi x^{-1})$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - was integrating the one with absolute value

Comment: Make the change of variable $\pi x^{-1}=t$ and break up the integral into $9$ parts, or $18$.

Comment: @AndreNicolas Thanks for that. Really makes sense.

Comment: You are welcome. When we break up the integral, we want $9$ times the area under $y=\sin w$, $w=0$ to $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already pointed out, substituting $u=\frac{\pi}{x}$ gives:

$$\int\frac{\pi}{x^2}sin\ \frac{\pi}{x}\ dx=\int-sin\ u\ du=cos\ u\ +C=cos\ \frac{\pi}{x}\ +C$$

The rest of the problem is dealing with the absolute value. Note that $x$ is strictly positive.

$$\int_{0.1}^1|\frac{\pi}{x^2}sin\ \frac{\pi}{x}|dx=\int_{0.1}^1\frac{\pi}{x^2}|sin\ \frac{\pi}{x}|dx$$

Using the same substitution, and putting bounds in terms of $u$:

$$=\int_\pi^{10\pi}|cos\ u|du$$

There are a number of ways of evaluating this intergal. One is to break in into subintervals where $cos\ u$ is strictly positive or negative and applying sign changes accordingly. Alternately, you can use geometry, and the observation that the integral between two consecutive roots of the cosine function is $\pm 2$.

$$=|\int_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}cos\ u\ du|+|\int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{\frac{5\pi}{2}}cos\ u\ du|+...+|\int_{\frac{17\pi}{2}}^{\frac{19\pi}{2}}cos\ u\ du|+|\int_{\frac{19\pi}{2}}^{10\pi}cos\ u\ du|$$

$$=1+2+...+2+1=1+8\cdot 2+1=18$$